# Переход goto от одной функций к другой

Tags: c

Всем добрый день! Почему в данном коде не получается перейти от одной функций к другой методом goto? Компилятор пишет что функции bar, fellodd и Elochka не определены.Даже если удалось запустить программу, она завершается без выполнения данной функций. Где то даже читал что это невозможно сделать. (По задумке функций должны были проигрывать определенные мелодии(Beep). Многоточия-замена части кода, не имеющей отношения к проблеме.

```
void bar( );
void feelgood( );
void elochka( );
void improv( );

int main()
{

... 

k=getch();

switch (k) {
case 1 : goto bar();
case 2 : goto feelgood();
case 3 : goto elochka();
default : return 0;
} // switch

return 0;
}// main


void elochka()
{
 ...   
}

void bar( )
{
...
}

void feelgood( )
{
...
}
```

Comment: Ну наверно начну с самого распространенного ответа в таком случае - не используйте goto НИКОГДА ! По сабжу - а где ваш .h файл ? Именно в нем определяются функции и наверняка именно поэтому ругается компилятор

Comment: Это не полный код. вырезал их потому что тут отображаются некорректно. Были подключены #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

Comment: И чем goto настолько плох? И есть ему замена в данном случае?

Comment: @Оскар, не работает, потому что идет неверное использование оператора goto

Comment: А что сделано не так?Даже если убрать goto, оставив просто вызов функций, то она все равно не выполняется

Comment: _А что сделано не так?_ - синтаксис. после goto должна следовать метка(label) куда надо перейти, у тебя таких меток нет. По сути ты и должен убрать goto в данном случае и у тебя останется обычный switch, а не выполняется он потом, что ты проверяешь не те метки. Посмотри _что_ возвращает функция _getch_

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос точное сообщение от компилятора, а не вашу его интерпретацию.

Comment: Компилятор пишет вот что: |70|error: label 'feelgood' used but not defined|. Про другие функций то же самое

Comment: По вашим вопросам - вам нужно изучить хотя бы какие-то азы языка. Увы, но такого рода вопрос не несет пользы никому, кроме вас...

Comment: @alexoander, что же плохого в `goto` (при условии чистого и понятного кода)?

Comment: @Оскар в том, что используя goto, вы нарушаете последовательность программы как таковой т.к. label по которому переходит goto можно поставить куда угодно. Насчет чистого и понятного кода - когда код не превышает строк 80 - на здоровье используйте (правда и там можно выстрелить в ногу). А вот когда проект разрастается использование goto является плохим тоном (за редким иссключением когда это "фича а не баг")

Comment: @alexoander, если правильно и вдумчиво использовать, то его можно применять. Половина ядра Linux в `goto`.

Comment: @0andriy спору нет - я сам видел это. Но, как вы и сказали, делать это надо вдумчиво и правильно. И это явно не для начинающего уровня разработки. Поэтому до поры до времени стоит запретить использование `goto` и бить по рукам за попытки его использовать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из стандарта языка C (6.8.1 Labeled statements)

```
1 labeled-statement: 
    identiﬁer : statement
```

и

> 3 Label names shall be unique within a function.

И, наконец, относительно `goto` предложения (6.8.6.1 The goto statement)

> 2 A goto statement causes an unconditional jump to the statement
>   preﬁxed by the named label in the enclosing function.

То есть вы можете использовать предложение `goto` в пределах одной функции, причем передавать управление на предложение, которому предшествует идентификатор, за которым следует двоеточие.

Очевидно, что данное предложение

```
goto bar();
```

по крайней мере синтаксически неверно, так как `bar()` не является меткой. А самое главное - вы не можете с помощью `goto` перескочить из одной функции в другую.

Похоже, все, что вам требуется, это просто вызвать соответствующие функции. Вы можете это сделать следующим образом.

```
switch (k) {
case 1 : bar(); break;
case 2 : feelgood(); break;
case 3 : elochka(); break;
default : return 0;
}
```

или в зависимости от типа и значения, хранимого в переменной `k`

```
switch (k) {
case '1' : bar(); break;
case '2' : feelgood(); break;
case '3' : elochka(); break;
default : return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вы хотели написать вот так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

void bar( );
void feelgood( );
void elochka( );
void improv( );

int main()
{

    int k = getch();

    switch (k) {
    case '1' : bar();
    case '2' : feelgood();
    case '3' : elochka();
    default : return 0;
    } // switch

    return 0;
}// main


void elochka()
{
    puts("elochka");
}

void bar( )
{
    puts("bar");
}

void feelgood( )
{
    puts("feelgood");
}
```

Компилируется и даже работает - при нажатии клавиш с цифрами 1, 2 и 3 выводятся названия функций.

Надеюсь, вас не удивляет, что при нажатии 1 вызываются все три функции?

`goto` работает только с *метками*. Но это отдельный вопрос, и `goto` действительно стоит использовать пореже...

Comment: По поводу сразу трех функций- это я давно заметил. Но почему так происходило- ответа дать не мог. А Puts - это какой то переход заместо goto?

Comment: @Оскар, аналог printf, но без форматирования и выводит только строки.

Comment: Попробовал ваш код, воспроизведение идет, но все равно при нажатий какой либо клавиши он не останавливается и воспроизводит дальше по списку.

Comment: @Оскар после нажатия 1- будет 3 ответа, 2 - 2 ответа, и только на 3 будет выведено 1. Почему? А потому что надо после каждого case ставить прерывание break; (как в примере выше)

Comment: При нажатии "какой-то" программа просто завершается. Функций несколько, потому что надо использовать `break`. И вообще, лихим кавалерийским наскоком языки не учатся, по вашим вопросам видно, что у вас совершенно нет никакого фундамента. Начните с какой-нибудь "C для чайников", честное слово, толку будет больше.